# Variable no especificada

Tags: python

tengo un problema llamando a un método, no detecta la variable total cuando la llamo desde el código principal solo detecta la variable global, he probado a pasarle la variable al método por parámetro y la reconoce pero no la suma correctamente

```
cesta_compra = {}
nombre = " "
total = 0

def add_item():
    nombre = input("introduce el nombre del articulo: ")
    precio = int(input("introduce el precio del articulo: "))
    cesta_compra[nombre] = precio
    
    total =+ precio
    

continuar = True
while continuar == True:
    print("cesta de la compra")
    add_item(0)
    continuar = input("escribe salir si quieres terminar: ")
    if continuar == "salir":
        continuar == False
    else:
        continuar = True
print(cesta_compra, " el total de la compra es: ", total)
```

Comment: El problema es que tienes la asignación de total alrevés. Se pone el `+` delante del `=`. Pon: `total += precio`

Comment: @ArianJM Eso no resolvería aún el problema, pues `total += precio` sigue creando una variable local, y sería accedida antes de estar inicializada, como explico en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Hay un par de problemas en el código. El primero es que llamas a `add_item(0)` pasándole un parámetro que el método no espera, por lo que la llamada da un error. Eso se resuelve fácilmente quitando ese `0` (¿qué significaba?)

El otro error más importante es el intento de modificar una variable global. Cuando en Python haces algo como esto:

```
total = 0

def ejemplo():
  print(total)

ejemplo()
```

La función `ejemplo()` se encuentra una referencia a una variable llamada `total`. Buscará esa variable "dentro" de la función y al no hallarla, la buscará después fuera (variables globales). Por tanto imprimirá 0 que es el valor de la variable global.

Hasta aquí todo bien. Un acceso de *lectura* a una variable global tendrá éxito siempre que no haya otra variable local con el mismo nombre.

Pero un intento de *escritura* (modificación) de una variable, causará que se cree una local con el mismo nombre, por lo que el siguiente código no hace lo que se buscaba:

```
total = 0

def ejemplo():
   total = 100
   print(total)

ejemplo()
print(total)
```

Python detecta que la función `ejemplo` contiene una asignación `total=` por lo que creará esa variable como local *dentro* de la función. La función imprimirá 100, pero ese será el valor de su variable local. La variable global seguirá valiendo 0 como se podrá comprobar con el `print()` final del programa principal.

Lo que es peor, python crea la variable local **antes incluso** de ejecutar la función, en una fase previa de "compilación", sólo por detectar que la función intenta modificar esa variable (sin que importe en qué punto de la función ocurra).

Por tanto lo siguiente nos reserva una sorpresa:

```
total = 0

def ejemplo():
   print(total)
   total = 100


ejemplo()
print(total)
```

¿Crees que el `print()` dentro de la función mostrará 0 (pues se referirá a la variable global) y que después se creará otra variable local que recibe el valor 100? Pues **no es eso** lo que ocurre.

Por el mero hecho de que Python observa una línea `total=` dentro de la función, esa variable se considera local. Todos los accesos que la función hace una variable llamada `total` se refieren a la local. Por tanto el primer `print(total)` fallará, pues está intentando mostrar el contenido de la variable local que **todavía no se ha asignado**.

Eso es en esencia lo que te está ocurriendo a tí. La variable `total` que intentas modificar dentro de la función, es local. Pero el `total += precio` es básicamente lo mismo que `total = total + precio`, es decir, se intenta consultar (en el lado derecho de la asignación) el valor de una variable que todavía no tiene valor.

### La solución

Cuando quieras modificar una variable global debes decirle a python que no cree esa variable local. Eso se le dice poniendo `global total` dentro de la función.

En mi ejemplo:

```
total = 0

def ejemplo():
   global total
   print(total)
   total = 100


ejemplo()
print(total)
```

Esto sí imprimirá 0 y luego 100.

## Consideraciones adicionales

Se considera en general mala práctica el uso de variables globales. Debes evitarlas. ¿Cómo podrías implementar entonces una solución a tu problema? Una forma podría ser que la función, en lugar de modificar variables globales, te devuelva datos para que sea el programa principal quien los agregue. Podría retornar por ejemplo el nombre y el precio. Pero esto parece no encajar bien con la idea de "add_product()", que por su nombre debería estar añadiendo en algún lugar los datos.

Pero si no es buena práctica añadirlo a variables globales, y por otro lado las variables locales no serían útiles (porque se pierden cuando la función termina) ¿cuál es la solución?

Para este tipo de casos lo mejor es usar programación Orientada a Objetos, y escribir una clase. Los atributos de la clase serían los datos, y los métodos de la clase serían los que manejan esos datos.

En este caso:

```
class Cesta:
  def __init__(self):
    self.cesta_compra = {}
    self.total = 0

  def add_item(self):
    nombre = input("introduce el nombre del articulo: ")
    precio = int(input("introduce el precio del articulo: "))
    self.cesta_compra[nombre] = precio
    self.total += precio

  def print(self):
    print(self.cesta_compra, " el total de la compra es: ", self.total)

print("Cesta de la compra")
cesta = Cesta()
continuar = ""
while continuar != "salir":
    cesta.add_item()
    continuar = input("escribe salir si quieres terminar: ")
cesta.print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes plantear de la siguiente forma el código, que la función devuelva el precio:

```
cesta_compra = {}
nombre = " "
total = 0

def add_item(a):
    nombre = input("introduce el nombre del articulo: ")
    precio = int(input("introduce el precio del articulo: "))
    cesta_compra[nombre] = precio
    return precio
    

continuar = True
while continuar == True:
    print("cesta de la compra")
    total = total + add_item(0)
    continuar = input("escribe salir si quieres terminar: ")
    if continuar == "salir":
        continuar == False
    else:
        continuar = True
print(cesta_compra, " el total de la compra es: ", total)
```

Tu código devuelve un error al llamar la función add_item con parámetro, cuando está definida sin él.

Te dejo otra forma de resolver el problema, utilizando una lista y obteniendo el total después una vez construida la lista:

```
continuar = True
cesta_compra = []
while continuar == True:
    nombre = input("Introduce el nombre del artículo: ")
    precio = float(input("Introduce el precio del artículo: "))
    try:
        precio = float(precio)
    except ValueError:
        print("Valor no válido, no es un número")
        break
        
    cesta_compra.append({"articulo":nombre, "precio":precio})
    
    salir = input("Escribe salir si quieres terminar: ")
    
    if (salir == "salir"):
        continuar = False
    else:
        continuar = True

print(cesta_compra)
total = 0
for c in cesta_compra:
    total = total + c['precio']

print(total)
```